Como evitar duplicados?
Estoy trabajando en una app con Android Studio, Kotlin y Firebase. Esta app consta de varios items. Entre ellos:
1.fecha actual
2.pisoSeleccionado
3.UnidadEvaluar
4.identificacionPaciente
A pesar de intentar con variaciones del codigo, no puedo evitar que existan duplicados.
Quedo atento a cualquier ayuda. Muchas gracias.
Este es parte del codigo utilizado:
// Función para verificar si una evaluación es duplicada
private fun isEvaluacionDuplicada(evaluacion: Evaluacion, callback: (Boolean) -> Unit) {
    val referencia = db.getReference("Evaluaciones")
    referencia.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            var duplicada = false
            for (snapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
                val evaluacionExistente = snapshot.getValue(Evaluacion::class.java)
                if (evaluacionExistente?.fecha == evaluacion.fecha &&
                    evaluacionExistente?.unidad == evaluacion.unidad &&
                    evaluacionExistente?.idPaciente == evaluacion.idPaciente) {
                    duplicada = true
                    break
                }
            }
            callback(duplicada)
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            callback(false)
        }
    })
}

// Función para guardar evaluación
private fun guardarEvaluacion(evaluacion: Evaluacion) {
    val fechaString = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(evaluacion.fecha)
    db.getReference("Evaluaciones")
        .orderByChild("compositeKey")
        .equalTo("${fechaString}${evaluacion.unidad}${evaluacion.idPaciente}")
        .limitToFirst(1)
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    // Ya existe una evaluación para este paciente y unidad en este día
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Evaluación duplicada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                } else {
                    // No existe una evaluación para este paciente y unidad en este día
                    val consecutivo = db.getReference("Evaluaciones").push().key ?: ""
                    db.getReference("Evaluaciones").child(consecutivo).setValue(evaluacion)
                        .addOnSuccessListener {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Evaluación guardada con éxito", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
                        .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Error al guardar evaluación: ${e.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error al verificar evaluación duplicada: ${error.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })
}

// Función para guardar datos
private fun guardarDatos() {
    val fechaActual = Calendar.getInstance().time
    val pisoSeleccionado = binding?.spinnerPiso?.selectedItem.toString()
    val unidadEvaluar = binding?.autocompleteUnidad?.text.toString()
    val identificacionPaciente = binding?.editTextPaciente?.text.toString()

    // Validaciones para asegurar datos completos
    if (pisoSeleccionado.isEmpty() || unidadEvaluar.isEmpty() || identificacionPaciente.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Por favor, seleccione un piso, unidad y la identificación", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        return
    }


Buenas, puedes ser mas preciso en DONDE ocurren los duplicados ??? El orden debería ser, al momento de guardar, tomar los valores a guardar, verificar si existen o no, y luego tratar de guardar.

Muchas gracias. Si, lo que quiero evitar, es que un mismo día, en una misma unidad, y con un mismo documento, se evite tomar el dato, allí lo que debería ocurrir es modificar la última evaluación realizada. Con mi código puedo ingresar los mismos datos y se seguirán guardando...y esto es lo que no he logrado corregir

Necesitas solo agregar una validación, pero por eso pregunte, cual función es la que te produce duplicados ahora, o son ambas ? por que hay 2 funciones que dicen guardar ahi

Buen dia. Quizas no he planteado bien mi dificultad. Lo que quiero deicr cuando digo "Evitar duplicados", me refiero a evitar que se guarden registros duplicados en tu base de datos. En este caso, específicamente, quieres evitar que se guarden evaluaciones duplicadas para la misma unidad y paciente en el mismo día. No se deberia permitir recolectar los mismos datos de la evaluacion. Para eso se deberia generar un mensaje preguntando si se quiere modificar, o no. Muchas gracias

Pero en firebase los documentos tienen una id, y no se pueden duplicar. Cuando guardas otra con la misma id lo que hace es actualizar
